# Replace UTF-8 string from email body to HTML entities

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a DB filled with textual mail bodies that were sent to customers and these are often written in non-english languages or contain pound/euro symbols.

Is there any function to replace these automatically with either the actual UTF-8 character or the HTML entity?

Here is an example of such email string:

```
Merci d'avoir choisi et f=C3=A9licitations pour vos gains !

D'apr=C3=A8s nos archives, une ou plusieurs demande(s) d'encaissement de votre part est (sont) en cours de traitement.

Les d=C3=A9tails de cet (ces) encaissement(s) sont les suivants :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`quoted_printable_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php):

```
$str = "Merci d'avoir choisi et f=C3=A9licitations pour vos gains ! D'apr=C3=A8s nos archives, une ou plusieurs demande(s) d'encaissement de votre part est (sont) en cours de traitement.Les d=C3=A9tails de cet (ces) encaissement(s) sont les suivants :";
echo quoted_printable_decode($str);
//Merci d'avoir choisi et félicitations pour vos gains ! D'après nos archives, une ou plusieurs demande(s) d'encaissement de votre part est (sont) en cours de traitement.Les détails de cet (ces) encaissement(s) sont les suivants :
```

They will be in utf-8 (in this case), so if you have charset header as utf-8, printing will work as is.